# c++ undefined reference to <a function>

Tags: c++, linux

HI,

I have some questions about .h files and .cpp files in c++/linux(ubuntu).

1. It is possible to compile a .h file using g++ or you can just compile a .cpp file that includes the .h file?
2. From a .h file and it's .cpp file (.cpp where i include some code to the methods i've defines in .h file) I create a .so file using the command:

   ```
   g++-fPIC -shared my_code.cpp -o my_code.so`
   ```

   In the `test.cpp` I include the .h file and using dlopen i create a handler over the .so file. Why do I have the following error:

   ```
   undefined reference to bool `Class::method(std::string)` `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   ```
3. If I say virtual bool method... in the .h file there is no error when I compile test.cpp. Can someone explain what am I doing wrong? The thing is that i have a template. With templates I cannot use virtual..so..i have this undefined error and i don't know how to resolve it. THX

EDIT:

When i compile the `my_code.cpp` I have the errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 12 (same with index 13,2,14...22 ).
```

But when i create the `.so` file there is no error . I use:

```
g++ test.coo -ldl -o test
```

for the test.cpp compilation.

Comment: I don't understand your second question. When do you get the error - is it when you compile my_code.cpp or when you compile test.cpp? If it is the latter: what exactly does the code in test.cpp look like?

Comment: Mention also command-line you use to compile `test.cpp`. It's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generally there is no need to compiling a `.h` file, it simply generates a huge file with `.gch` extension I guess.
2. The error you are getting is a link time. While creating the `.so` file, you do not actually link the code. So all undefined symbol are assumed to be present at some place. When you link it, the linker will find for those symbols. So, you should compile/link all the .cpp file together. The error will go away.

Also, For `templates`, the **definition of the code must always be visible**. So wherever you write the templated function/variable definition, include that file everywhere.

**Edit**:
You can have `virtual` method with template classes; but you can not have `virtual template methods`.

```
template<typename T>
class A {
  virtual void foo(int); // ok
};

class A {
  template<typename T>
  virtual void foo(T); // illegal
};
```

Comment: The first point is misleading (unless you explain what `.gch` file is and when you want to use it) and I don't see how the second and third point relate to the question.

Comment: @iammilind: The answer doesn't answer the OP's Questions.

Comment: what do you mean by virtual methods with template classes?

Comment: How can I create an generic object? I have a class that contains a lot of methods. One of my methods has a generic object as a parameter. How to do that/

Comment: @linuxx, to have a generic object inside a method, you can declare that method `template` (not `virtual`). Such as `template<typename T> void foo(T &obj);`. Also, if you feel that your question will have a descriptive answer then you can choose to write a new one. So it can be addressed properly. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1: It is possible to compile `.h` file (you can explicitly override the language detection), but you don't want to do it. The `.h` file is intended to be included and will not compile to anything useful on it's own.

Ad 2: You have to *link* against the library you created by passing the `-lmy_code` (but note that for that to work you have to create it as `libmy_code.so`) along with appropriate `-L` flag (directory where you placed `libmy_code.so`) to the linker. Like this:

```
g++ test.cpp -L. -lmy_code -ldl -o test
```

But you also have to change the first command to:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared my_code.cpp -o libmy_code.so
                                 ^^^
                                 libraries *must* have `lib` prefix on unix systems.
```

and this assumes both are done in the same directory—if not, you have to adjust the `-L` option to point to the directory where libmy_code.so is. Also you have to place `libmy_code.so` somewhere where the dynamic linker can find it. Either by installing it or by setting environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to appropriate directory. Alternatively you can compile by using

```
g++ test.cpp my_code.so -ldl -o test
```

This does not force the `lib` prefix and it creates an "rpath" entry in the binary so it will find the library in the original place.

This all assumes you want to use it as regular library in which case you **don't want to use dlopen**. `dlopen` is for opening libraries as plugins at runtime and than they can only be accessed by fetching pointers to symbols using `dlsym()`, but if you want to access the library normally, you have to link against it so the linker can resolve the symbols.

If instead you wanted to use `dlopen`, you **must not include** `my_code.h` in `test.cpp` and **must not use** anything it defines except by getting the symbols with `dlsym`. And since this is C++, it in turn requires you understand the symbol mangling scheme, because `dlsym` will not do this for you.

Comment: I am usinf dlsym in my test.cpp code.WHst is with that -L flag? YOu mean i am not correctly compile my .so file?